# How would I be able to take a card from hand1 and give it to hand2?

Tags: python, list, indexing, blackjack

I want to know if there is a way in def main where I can take the first random card from hand1 and be able to transfer it to hand2.

At first I tried something like this, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
i = hand[0]
i.give(0, hands[1])
```

The card shuffle randomly to each hand can have a different set of cards each time, which creates a problem cause there technically isn't a list that I can index from.

```
class Card(object):  
    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
             "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    SUITS = ["c", "d", "h", "s"]
    
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank 
        self.suit = suit
    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.rank + self.suit
        return rep

class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
           rep = ""
           for card in self.cards:
               rep += str(card) + "  "
        else:
            rep = ("<empty>")
        return rep

    def clear(self):
        self.cards = []
        
    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)
        
    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)

class Deck(Hand):
    """ A deck of playing cards. """
    def populate(self):
        for suit in Card.SUITS:
            for rank in Card.RANKS: 
                self.add(Card(rank, suit))
    def shuffle(self):
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, hands, per_hand = 1):
        for rounds in range(per_hand):
            for hand in hands:
                if self.cards:
                    top_card = self.cards[0]
                    self.give(top_card, hand)
                else:
                    print ("Out of cards!")


class Unprintable_Card(Card):
    def __str__(self):
        return "<Unprintable>"

class Positionable_Card(Card):
    def __init__(self, rank, suit, face_up = True):
        super(Positionable_Card, self).__init__(rank, suit)
        self.is_face_up = face_up

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_face_up:
            rep = super(Positionable_Card, self).__str__()
        else:
            rep = "XX"
        return rep
    def flip(self):
        self.is_face_up = not self.is_face_up



    
def main():



    deck1 = Deck()
    deck1.populate()
    deck1.shuffle()
    print("\nShuffled the deck.")
    print("Deck:")
    print(deck1)

    hand1 = Hand()
    hand2 = Hand()
    hand3 = Hand()
    hand4 = Hand()
    hand5 = Hand()
    hands = [hand1, hand2, hand3, hand4, hand5]

    deck1.deal(hands,per_hand = 5)

    print("\nDealt 5 cards to my hand and your hand.")
    print("Hand 1:")
    print(hand1)
    print("Hand 2:")
    print(hand2)
    print("Hand 3:")
    print(hand3)
    print("Hand 4:")
    print(hand4)
    print("Hand 5:")
    print(hand5)
    print(hands[0] letters)


    #i = hand[0]
    #i.give(0, hands[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

the first argument of `give()` should be a card in the hand, not an index

something like this should work:

```py
hand1.give(hand1.cards[0], hand2)
```